# Can I have kitniot in my house on Pesach if I cannot eat them?

Tags: halacha, passover, ashkenazi, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

The question boils down to:

Can I have kitniot in my house on Pesach if I cannot eat them (in the Ashkenazic tradition)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can own them (Rama in [Shulchan Aruch OC 453:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49627&st=&pgnum=96)). The Mishna Berura there adds that you can even derive benefit from them.

Comment: And according to many ashkanazic rishonim you can even eat them!