# What can I feed my elderly cat during Pesach?

Tags: passover, product-recommendation, animals, chametz-leaven, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

I have a 19-year-old cat who is (now) on a low-protein diet, precluding the canonical week of tuna.  Is there someplace I can buy chametz-free, low-protein food?  Are there any consequences (for me) if the cat eats kitniyot?  ([Owning kitniyot is permitted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14979/472), I know, and the cat has his own dish and spoon.)

Comment: CYLOR (of course)

Comment: @HachamGabriel, and my vet, but I'm hoping to take advantage of any information that could inform the discussions.  (Particularly if somebody already knows places to buy safe pet food.)

Comment: Since infants can eat kitniyos, it seems to me that cats can all the more so.

Comment: @yoel I agree with your conclusion, but can you source the first part of your comment?

Comment: @yoel, it's possible that instead we say "we can violate kitniyot restrictions for a child but not for an animal".  I don't know; I can just see that argument going either way.  The cat is of course not forbidden from eating kitniyot since he's not Jewish; the issues (if any) would be in a Jew preparing the food.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It is, though, forbidden to feed one's animals chametz because you would thereby be deriving benefit from the chametz, so the thought to extend it to kitniyot (which we are somewhat "worried" are chametz) is not "of course" wrong.

Comment: **Congratulations! This question won the [weekly topic challenge](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/441) for the week of Vayakhel-P'kude 5772!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This list from the [Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-petfood.htm) has many items that you can feed your cat on Pesach.

Per the [CRC-Chicago](http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/pdf/crc_passover_2012_pets.pdf)

> Kitniyot ingredients, such as corn and rice, are acceptable in pet
>   foods for Passover, because while Ashkenazim do not customarily eat
>   kitniyot, they are permitted to own and benefit from them.