# Dog food on Pesach

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

If a brand of dog food contains no grains, and none of the types of dog food produced by the company contain any grains how should it be approached in terms of kashrus for Passover? Do people have thoughts on this and/or know of any sources regarding pet food on Passover that might be relevant?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you [edit] your question to make it less personal? We [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Here are some related questions: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75842/5323, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56292/5323

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67060 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15229

Answer (score 1):

This is from the OU

> Since it is forbidden to own or benefit from chametz during Passover, food that contains chametz may not be fed to pets. However, it is permitted to give pets food that contains kitniyot.
>   If one is unable to procure pet food that does not contain chametz, some rabbinical authorities allow for a sale, which would transfer to a gentile the ownership and responsibility of caring for the pet. Ask your Rabbi for guidance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should add that this implies that the specified dog food would be allowed for Pesach.

Comment: What does the sale clause mean practically?

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this from the CRC about pet food on Passover that is more comprehensive than the OU advice above. It includes info on what ingredients might be problematic:

> "The following are some pointers when reading the ingredient panel:
>
> In addition to checking for the five chametz grains - wheat, barley, rye, oats >and spelt - you should also be on the lookout for brewer's yeast (a common >flavoring agent, which is chametz), malt (a barley-based sweetener), pasta, >xanthan gum (a thickener which may be fermented from chametz) and other generic >words which may refer to a chametz ingredient (e.g. flour, gluten, middlings, >starch).
>   Many varieties of animal feed contain a multitude of vitamins, minerals and amino >acids some of which may well be chametz and there is no realistic way for a >consumer to determine which of them are problematic. However, the good news is >that vitamins comprise such a small percentage of the animal food that the >vitamins are batel. Therefore, it is generally accepted that if the animal food >was created before Pesach it may be used on Pesach.
>   Some common ingredients used in pet food which do not pose a Pesach concern are:
>   Animal, poultry and fish products.
>   Vegetables, such as alfalfa, asparagus, beets, and carrots.
>   Assorted kitnios foods, such as buckwheat, corn products, lentils, millet, peas, >rice, peanuts, sunflower seeds and soy products.
>   Other items such as barley grass, BHA, BHT, carrageenan, cellulose, colors, eggs, >gums (other than xanthan gum), kelp, lactose, linseed, milk products, molasses, >oils, psyllium, and whey."

http://www.kashrut.com/Passover/PetFoodPassover/