# Is Ethanol Mixed Gasoline Kosher for Passover

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Typically in the US, gasoline for cars is a mixture of refined crude oil and some ethanol up to 10%.

Since ethanol in the US is corn based, by buying gasoline are you buying kitniyot?

Comment: You are allowed to own Kitniyot. No problem.

Comment: But I thought there was an issue buying it during Pesach, if you own it you could just put it away.

Comment: http://select.nytimes.com/2007/04/01/nyregion/01towns.html?_r=1 Note: This was an April 1st article. Anyway, the technical answer to your question is that once the mixture is inedible to a dog, it is permitted outright. So even if it was wheat based ethanol it wouldn't be a problem (assuming a dog won't sip gasoline - I never experimented).

Comment: I recommend that you consult your rabbi and your dietitian before drinking an ethanol-gasoline mixture on Passover.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I am not talking about drinking it, I'm talking about deriving benefits from it.

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14979/759

Comment: No problem in own kitnoyit, no problem in deriving benefit from it and another secret -- no problem in eating it!

Comment: @Yehoshua For Sefardim, maybe, but us Ashkenazim have long since accepted not to eat Kitniyos on Pesach.

Answer (score 6):

[Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/toiletries-on-pesach.html) goes through the various opinions of toiletries that contain alcohol over Pesach. He explains why it isn't a problem.

> R’ Ovadia Yosef (Yalkut Yosef 447:2) permits using products that contain denatured alcohol on Pesach. R’ Chaim Elazar Shapira (Minchas Elazar 5:37) writes that while people are particular, once alcohol has been denatured, it is not considered rauy l’achilah. Thus one may drive a car (on Erev Yom Tov and Chol Hamoed) even if the petrol is mixed with denatured alcohol.